# IF Statements in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Assuming I have have a text box and a button on a page written in Rails what would be the code to compare a string inputted in that box with another string (non-dynamic)?

Does Rails have the same structure as Java when testing If statements like:

```
IF text1 = text2 Then
... do something ...
Else
... do something ...
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Read some basic Ruby websites/books. Google "ruby if statement". You'll find information there.

Comment: You are asking an extremely basic question which any tutorial on Ruby will cover in its first chapters.

Comment: It sounds like you need to look at the basics of Ruby, for example [in the Pragmatic Programmer book](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/intro.html) (which does contain if statements among other fundamental concepts)

Comment: Please, next time google a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller

```
if params[:text_box_name_1].to_s == params[:text_box_name_2].to_s

  ----
else

end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if text1 == text2
  ...
elsif text2 == text3
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures#if_expression

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#if

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-if-else-if-command-syntax/